# Necesito ayuda para hacer uso de tooltip en mi app

Tags: angular, tooltip

Buen día a todos (as), Hace días que trato de incorporar el uso de tooltip en un componente que despliega una serie de select dependiendo de la respùesta devuelta por el servidor y necesito que al posar el mouse en cualquiera de sus items se depliegue un toolip customizable (quiero configurar fuentes y colores). Hasta ahora he probado un sinnúmero de alternativas, pero no he conseguido que me funcionen... un dato importante es que los select y sus respectivos items se forman a partir de un ngFor anidado. Adjunto el código que tengo y agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar:

**mi controlador:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router,ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import { CepalstatService } from '../../services/cepalstat.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-artista',
  templateUrl: './artista.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./artista.component.css'],
  providers: [CepalstatService]
})
export class ArtistaComponent implements OnInit{

  public respuesta: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _cepalstatService: CepalstatService


    ) {

    }

  ngOnInit(){

        this._route.params.subscribe( params => {

            var search = params['id'];

        this._cepalstatService.search(search).subscribe(

          response => {

            console.log('Mi Response trae: ', response);
            this.respuesta = response.body.dimensions;
            console.log('Mi Respuesta trae: ', this.respuesta);

          },
          error => {
            console.log('Para, para... Paraaaa, tenemos un error!! : ',error);

          }

        );

        console.log(params, ",  y: ", search);


        });

  }
}
```

**Mi html:**

```
<!-- ngFor para componentes con Select-->
<div *ngFor = "let valores1 of respuesta">
    {{valores1.name}}
    <div class="input-field col s12 ">
            <select class="Sebas1" multiple="multiple">
              <option value="" *ngFor="let valores of valores1.members" >
                        {{valores.name}}
                        <span class="sebasTest">
                          {{valores.name}}
                        </span>
              </option>


            </select>
            <label>Seleccione lo que pueda</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

El tooltip que querría usar (pero no se cómo habilitarlo):

**Controlador:**

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Tooltip that can have a custom class applied.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip-custom-class-example',
  templateUrl: 'tooltip-custom-class-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tooltip-custom-class-example.css'],
  // Need to remove view encapsulation so that the custom tooltip style defined in
  // `tooltip-custom-class-example.css` will not be scoped to this component's view.
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class TooltipCustomClassExample {}
```

**El html:**

```
<button mat-raised-button
        matTooltip="Info about the action"
        matTooltipClass="example-tooltip-red"
        aria-label="Button that shows a red tooltip"
        class="example-button">
  Red-tooltip Action
</button>
```

**Estilos:**

```
.example-button {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.example-tooltip-red {
  background: #b71c1c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El Tooltip lo puedes agregar a cualquier elemento.

```
<!-- ngFor para componentes con Select-->
<div *ngFor = "let valores1 of respuesta">
    {{valores1.name}}
    <div class="input-field col s12 ">
            <select class="Sebas1" multiple="multiple">
              <option value="" *ngFor="let valores of valores1.members" 
                 matTooltip="{{valores.info}}">
                        {{valores.name}}
                        <span class="sebasTest">
                          {{valores.name}}
                        </span>
              </option>


            </select>
            <label>Seleccione lo que pueda</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

De esta manera lo puedes agregar sin necesidad de otro componente

Por el contrario, si aun deseas utilizar el segundo componente deberias agregar el selector  en tu select y modificar el html porque genera un botón.